# What happens if I exceed the current limit at the GPIO pins of the Pico?

Tags: pigpio, pi-pico, current

They say that the output current of the Pico GPIO is configurable (2, 4, 8, 12mA). What does it means ? If I choose 8mA, what will happen if I connect a bigger load ? Will the curent be limited to 8mA, or the chip will break ? If it is not limited, what is the point to have configurable output current ? If the chip can support 12mA max why someone will choose to set it lower ? What benefits would I have if I select it to be lower ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RPi Pico: Is it dangerous to set GPIO drive strength of 12mA on all the UART-related pins, assuming there are 2 small LEDs connected to other pins?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/145907/rpi-pico-is-it-dangerous-to-set-gpio-drive-strength-of-12ma-on-all-the-uart-rel)